# How can I draw a dotted line with arrow using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-trees

I've tried the following code, which didn't produce the line I expected.

```
\draw[-->] (have) [in=-90, out=-90, looseness=2.5] to (non);
```

Comment: Welcome. Have you seen the [manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.3.2)? Use any of the predefined keys, e.g. `dotted`, or define your own `dash pattern`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can not be compiled:

- not defined MWE (Minimal working Example), a complete small document
- not defined coordinates ˛`have` and `non`
- wrong used sintax

So, just guessing, that you are after something like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[dotted, ->]  (0,0) to [in=-90, out=-90, looseness=2.5]   (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you might prefer to use `bbox`for define "smart" bounding box around your image, which eliminate white space below image:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]                        ]
\ \draw[dotted,->]  (0,0) to [in=-90, out=-90, looseness=2.5]   (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]